# Pig's "dump" is not working on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig

I am trying Pig commands on EMR of AWS. But even small commands are not working as I expected. What I did is following.

1. Save the following 6 lines as `~/a.csv`.

   ```
   1,2,3
   4,2,1
   8,3,4
   4,3,3
   7,2,5
   8,4,3
   ```
2. Start Pig
3. Load the csv file.

   ```
   grunt> A = load './a.csv' using PigStorage(',');
   16/01/06 13:09:09 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
   ```
4. Dump the variable A.

   ```
   grunt> dump A;
   ```

But this commands fails. I expected that this command produces 6 tuples which are described in a.csv. The dump commands a lot of INFO lines and ERROR lines. The ERROR lines are following.

```
91711 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats  - ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
16/01/06 13:10:08 ERROR pigstats.PigStats: ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
91711 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil  - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
16/01/06 13:10:08 ERROR mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil: 1 map reduce job(s) failed!

[...skipped...]

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://ip-xxxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/a.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://ip-xxxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8020/tmp/temp-718505580/tmp344967938"

[...skipped...]

91718 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias A. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
16/01/06 13:10:08 ERROR grunt.Grunt: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias A. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
```

(I have changed IP-like description.) The error message seems to say that the load operator also fails.

I have no idea why even the dump operator fails. Can you give me any advice?

Note

- I also use TAB in a.csv instead commas and execute `A = load './a-tab.csv';`, but it does not help.
- `$ pig -x local` -> `A = load 'a.csv' using PigStorage(',');` -> `dump A;`. Then

  ```
  Input(s):
  Failed to read data from "file:///home/hadoop/a.csv"
  ```

  If I use the full path, namely `A = load '/home/hadoop/a.csv' using PigStorage(',');`, then I get

  ```
  Input(s):
  Failed to read data from "/home/hadoop/a.csv"
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem. You may try to `su root` use the root user, then  `./bin/pig` at `PIG_HOME` to start pig in mapreduce mode. On the other hand, you also can use the current user by `sudo ./bin/pig` at `PIG_HOME` to start pig, but you must export `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` in the `./bin/pig` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your local file system, you should have to start your pig in step 2 as below

```
bin/pig -x local
```

If you start just as `bin/pig` that will search the file in DFS. That's why you get error `Failed to read data from "hdfs://ip-xxxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/a.csv"`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the local mode. But I get different errors. I added the details about it in my post. (There is no difference when I use pig's full path "/usr/bin/pig".)

Comment: Use full path of the file.i don't think a.csv is in /home/hadoop